# function called on page load not jquery .click

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function gets called on page load, not when .somebutton is clicked. I'm not sure why. I want to be able to pass the variables so that I may use this function in multiple places with different values. Thank you very much.

```
var i = "this be i";
var u = "this be u";

function dosomething (var1, var2){
    console.log(var1 + " and " + var2);
}

$(".somebutton").click(dosomething(i,u));
```

Comment: fiddle or does not exist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing value returned by `dosomething(i,u)` to `click` handler. This is why it ise executing without clicking, it is happening as soon as you call your function (that is: `dosomething(i,u)`). You need to wrap your function call inside anonymous function:

```
$(".somebutton").click(function() { dosomething(i,u); } );
```

Comment: yeah, I didn't see the variables declared outside

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass a function by reference using the method in your example (ie. without parameters). The reason your function works on load is because it is immediately invoked due to the trailing `()` brackets.

If you need to pass parameters you need to wrap it in an anonymous function, like this:

```
// on click:
$(".somebutton").click(function() {
    dosomething(i, u);
});

// on page load:
dosomething(i, u);
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript doing

```
$(".somebutton").click(dosomething(i,u));
```

will not assign the function to your click event, but will rather call the function and assign whatever result the function returns. You need to reference your function instead :

```
$(".somebutton").click(dosomething);
```

If you need to pass variables to your function, then you need to wrap the said function inside another anonymous one :

```
$(".somebutton").click(function() { dosomething(i, u); });
```

Comment: thanks this is the first time I really understood why this behavior makes sense.